# Android - Create multi-segmented section in horizontal bar

Tags: android, graph, bar-chart, mpandroidchart

I want to create a multi-segmented section in the horizontal bar, as you can see in the screenshot i have posted. You can in the first bar , I have to create 5 segments and i have a total count of 20. now in the first bar the first segment will cover 5% of the total count i.e. from 20% and so on.
enter image description here

[image]